# Does Guiding Bolt reveal a Gloom Stalker ranger in darkness?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, ranger, vision-and-light, invisibility

The *Guiding Bolt* says:

> A flash of light streaks toward a creature of your choice within range. Make a ranged spell attack against the target. On a hit, the target takes 4d6 radiant damage, and the next attack roll made against this target before the end of your next turn has advantage, thanks to the mystical dim light glittering on the target until then.

Does this "dim light" on a Gloom Stalker ranger makes it visible in darkness? My first thought was no, because spells don't do more than their descriptions says they do and *Guiding Bolt* doesn't reveal invisible creatures in general, but the spell explicitly said "dim light" "on the target" which the ranger would be visible in, so I'm not sure.

The Gloom Stalker's Umbral Sight ability:

> At 3rd level, you gain darkvision out to a range of 60 feet. If you already have darkvision from your race, its range increases by 30 feet.
>
> You are also adept at evading creatures that rely on darkvision. While in darkness, you are invisible to any creature that relies on darkvision to see you in that darkness.

Answer (score 25):

A strict reading of the rules as written, I believe you answered your own question here. If the Gloom Stalker is hit with Guiding Bolt, there is mystical dim light on them. If they are inside of dim light, they are not in darkness, so they would not benefit from their Umbral Sight ability.

Of course if you are the DM you can make any decision that makes sense in your game and head cannon for your table. If you are a player, always speak to your DM about expectations about rules as written, and their own understandings and interpretations of rules. At the end of the day D&D is a game and we should be cognisant of how these rulings affect everyone we play with. I hope my answer helps.

Comment: dim light is dim light

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/dGF64ON.jpg